# Datatables single column search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a basic table and I would like to search only **one** column.

The code I have so far is [here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/u14Lorsr/1/).

As you can see at the bottom of each column there is a search filter, however I would only like there to be one search filter, on the `office` column.

It would also be good if the search filter was at the top, and not at the bottom as it is now.

Basically I'd like my table to look similar to [this one](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html), however instead of a filter on each column, I only want **one** filter on **one** column.

Any help is appreciated.

My code is below.

```js
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;

  $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
      that
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$4,525</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$4,525</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Russell Chavez</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your code

```
$('#example tfoot th').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});
```

with

```
$('#example thead th').each(function() {

  var title = $(this).text();
  if(title == 'Office'){
  $(this).append('<br /><input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
  }
});
```

as you can see I replaced tfoot to thead to set the search box  on top. 
and I placed the condition to display the search box for "office"

Comment: Thanks @Mitali but this doesn't seem to be working. Have you tried it? The search results don't filter correctly, and they seem to filter once the input box is clicked in.

Comment: Ohhh sorry for the miss. You need to replace "$('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() " to " $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() " as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I know this question has already been answered,
>
> Nevertheless, it might be of use to some people...

---

## Alternative Minimized Example :

From :

```
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;

  $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
      that
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
```

---

To :

```
 //Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
 $('#example tfoot th').each(function(i) {
  var title = $(this).text();
  var events = 'onchange="SearchCol(this,'+i+')"'
      events+= ' onkeyup="SearchCol(this,'+i+')"'
  $(this).html('<input type="text" '+events+' placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
 });
 // Search Specific Column
 function SearchCol(input,col_index){
  var query = $(input).val()
  $("#example").DataTable().column(col_index).search(query).draw()
 }
```