# Add & remove more column based searches/filters to datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to add some button which create on click a search/filter for a datatable.

```
<button class="seachbutton" id="searchbutton_1" data-column="0" data-value="lookforthis_A">
<button class="seachbutton" id="searchbutton_2" data-column="1" data-value="lookforthis_B">
<button class="seachbutton" id="searchbutton_3" data-column="2" data-value="lookforthis_C">
```

I add a column-bases search with this code from the datatables examples

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
$('.searchbutton').on( 'click', function () {
    table
        .columns( $(this).attr("data-column") )
        .search( $(this).attr("data-value"))
        .draw();
} );
```

If I click on a button the filter/search for the clicked button works fine.

Now if I click at a second button, this search should additional to the existing search (after first click on button1).

For Example
First click on a button - query: "Column=0&value=lookforthis_A"

Click at another button -query: "Column=0&value=lookforthis_A & Column=1&value=lookforthis_B"

How can I do this?

Also I have to remove the searches/filters by click the button again - how can I do this too?

Comment: Using an array should work: `columns( [2,3] )`. See the [column selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) documentation.

Comment: Or, for all columns, use `columns.every()` as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select). Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225335/datatables-single-column-search) where their starting point looks like what you might want (every column has its own search box).

Comment: ok i trie it with a array, is there a way to remove a single search from agein?

Comment: @andrewjames could you give me a smal example, how i can add a new search for another column to a existing search for the other columns?

Comment: Did changing `columns( 2 )` to `columns( [2,3] )` not work? Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do...

Comment: @andrewjames my problem is, that i create the filter dynamically so i dont know how many filters on wich columns are already defined.

Comment: OK - I _think_ what you are asking about is a variable - for example, `var colFilters = []` and then you dynamically populate that array as needed, each time the page is refreshed. So, for example, colFilters might be `[ 1,2,4,7 ]` - and then you use that variable in your DataTable definition: `columns( colFilters )`. That way, you re-apply the filters for every page refresh. Is that the requirement? If so, who chooses the columns?

Comment: @andrewjames, i'm not sure for 100% but it could be that what I'm looking for. I want to add some buttons. Each button should activate a single search but after clicking more ase one button the searc hase to combine. Also i have to remove it in the same way. Maybe this made it a bit more clear?

Comment: What does "the search has to combine" mean? Perhaps you can [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking. Show what you have tried, and show what _specific_ problem you are facing.

Comment: @andrewjames sure, i've update my question, hope its more clear what i trie to do